# Can I play as a Changeling?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, changeling

I will be playing my first D&D-campaign soon and I want to play as a changeling.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you playing in an official Adventurers League?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### If you are in Eberron

The Changeling is available in the book *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*:

> Humanoids of all kinds have made their mark on the continent of Khorvaire. Presented in alphabetical order, the playable races in this section have especially shaped the land’s recent history.
>
> [...]
>
> **Changelings** are clever shapechangers who can disguise themselves as other people.

Whether or not you are allowed to play as one in a different setting (or even in certain campaigns set in Eberron) will depend on your GM. Some GMs are happy to allow the reflavoring of races from other worlds into the stats from specific settings, but other GMs want to maintain a particular set of races for the player characters. If you aren't in Eberron, **ask your GM**.

### Adventurers League play

Season 9 of Adventurer's League (the current season as of this edit), is ssplit into two campaigns. One of them is set in the Forgotten Realms and *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* is not a valid source for character options in that campaign.

However, it is a valid source (and therefore changelings are a valid race) in the Oracle of War campaign which is set in Eberron (in fact it is the only valid source beyond the *Player's Handbook* and *Basic Rules*).

More information can be found in the [Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack).